# rextester restful api json errors

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp, restful-url

Good day everyone. I was trying to send a post request on rextester restful API that will return a json string, but it will just throw an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://rextester.com/rundotnet/api. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

with my code:

```
    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://rextester.com/rundotnet/api', 
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      accepts: "application/json",
      success: function(data) {
          console.log( "success" + JSON.stringify( data ) );
      }, error: function (data) {
          console.log( "error" + JSON.stringify( data ) );
      }, complete: function ( data ) {
          console.log( "complete" + JSON.stringify( data ) );
      }
  });
```

but if i change the dataType to **jsonp** the error would recede to

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : rextester.com/rundotnet/api?callback=jQuery110202748815272934735_1409212747…%22Hello,%20Worlds!\%22);%20}%20}%22,%22Input%22:%22%22}&_=1409212747488:1`

which if i click will show the return value that i'm expecting in json format from the console: `{"Warnings":null,"Errors":"Method \u0027main\u0027 must be in a class \u0027Rextester\u0027.","Result":"","Stats":"Compilation time: 0.84 sec, absolute service time: 0.85 sec","Files":null}`

any suggestions? tnx
The API only supports POST requests and will return a JSON string value.

Comment: I've added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the response header. Your initial approach should be working now.

Comment: Also it's probably better to make such request from the server side since probably not all browsers support cross-origin requests.

Comment: i've added `<?php 
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://rextester.com'); 
?>` to my php file but the error still appears

Comment: No, I've meant that I added that header when you call http://rextester.com/rundotnet/api (I'm the maintainer of rextester). If that didn't do the trick then you should do the call from the server side.